# How can I extract individual words and urls from a text?

Tags: java, url, text

I am trying to extract words from a text. My text looks like this:

```
String text = "This is my text and it contains a url: http://www.google.com";
String[] words = text.split("\\W+");
```

The problem here is that this way the url is broken down to words like http www google com and it becomes useless for me.

Instead what I would like to have is an array like this:

```
This
is
my
text
and
it
contains
a
url
http://www.google.com
```

Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] words = text.split(" ");
```

Will return [This, is, my, text, and, it, contains, a, url:, http://www.google.com]

Answer (score 0):

I would go with

```java
text.split("\\s+");
```

In regex, `\s` matches **any** whitespace characters, against `split(" ")` which will only match the unicode `\u0020`